# SFML Player movement issue

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm making a game in SFML library and I'm trying to make the `Player` move. I have no clue why it isn't moving while im pressing Right Arrow Key.

Game.cpp

```
#include "Game.h"

Game::Game()
{
windowWidth = 800;
windowHeight = 600;
}

Game::~Game()
{
}

void Game::Start()
{
window.create(sf::VideoMode(windowWidth, windowHeight), "Game");
window.setFramerateLimit(60);

while (window.isOpen())
{
    sf::Event e;
    while (window.pollEvent(e))
    {
        if (e.type == sf::Event::Closed || sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Escape))
        {
            window.close();
        }
        else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left))
        {
        }
        else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right))
        {
            character.MoveRight();
        }
    }

    character.SetPosition(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    character.UpdatePosition();
    Draw();
}
}

void Game::Draw()
{
window.clear();

character.DrawPlayer(window);

window.display();
}
```

Player.cpp

```
#include "Player.h"

Player::Player()
{
player.setSize(sf::Vector2f(200, 50));
player.setFillColor(sf::Color::White);

playerX = 300;
playerY = 300;
playerSpeed = 5.f;
}

Player::~Player()
{
}

void Player::MoveRight()
{
playerX += playerSpeed;
}

void Player::SetPosition(float windowWidth, float windowHeight)
{
playerX = windowWidth / 2 - 100;
playerY = windowHeight - 50;
}

void Player::UpdatePosition()
{
player.setPosition(playerX, playerY);
}

void Player::DrawPlayer(sf::RenderWindow &window)
{
window.draw(player);
}
```

Feel free to tell me what should I change in my code.

Answer (score 0):

So here is what's going on in your main loop:

```
   character.SetPosition(windowWidth, windowHeight); // Put this line to get a start location
   while (window.isOpen())
   {
        sf::Event e;
        while (window.pollEvent(e))
        {
            // your code...
        }

        character.SetPosition(windowWidth, windowHeight); // <---- Remove this line
        character.UpdatePosition();
        Draw();
    }
}
```

You are constantly setting the characters position to `windowWidth`, and `windowHeight`, so regardless of you calling `character.MoveRight()`, you are always reseting the position.

I would also recommend adding something for handling input controls, maybe even placing them inside of your `Player` in an `update` method, and removing them for your event loop, as that can run multiple times and will hit your `character.MoveRight()` multiple times.

Last bit of advice look into SFML's clock, so you can move your characters smoothly based off of time instead of framerate.